# Same configuration in Kafka Producer, Broker and Topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I see few configurations which are a part of configuration list of brokers, producers as well as topics like: `compression.type`

How does all 3 configs work together?
Like, if we I have `compression.type` in producer config as None, and `compression.type` in broker config as gzip. How does it work?

There are similarly other configs too, like `min.insync.replicas.`
My understanding is, it should be a Topic configuration (which it is), but it is also a broker configuration.
Is it something like - a broker has say `min.insync.isr` as 4, so all the topics created on that broker will have `min.insync.isr` as 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The broker configs are defaults. Everything else is an explicit override.